# how to test jwt sample? and what are userid?

Tags: oauth, docusignapi

My development Environment : eclipse java

I would like test a `requestJWTuserToken` sample, but I'm getting an error.

Test code:

```java
OAuth.OAuthToken oAuthToken = apiClient.requestJWTUserToken(IntegratorKey, userId, scopes, privateKeyBytes, 3600);
Assert.assertNotSame(null, oAuthToken);

apiClient.setAccessToken(oAuthToken.getAccessToken(), oAuthToken.getExpiresIn());
UserInfo userInfo = apiClient.getUserInfo(oAuthToken.getAccessToken());
Assert.assertNotSame(null, userInfo);
Assert.assertNotNull(userInfo.getAccounts());
Assert.assertTrue(userInfo.getAccounts().size() > 0);
```

---

Error message:

> com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: **Error while requesting an access token:**

```
class OAuthToken {
    accessToken: null
    tokenType: null
    refreshToken: null
    expiresIn: 0
```

> at com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient.requestJWTUserToken(ApiClient.java:719)
>   
>    at smartsuite.app.util.DocuSignUtil.settingAuthentication(DocuSignUtil.java:112)

what are userid?

I found a admin sendbox at user > API username
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM5DM.jpg)

Comment: Hi, which sample in particular are you testing?  Please link to it.  Also what language are you programming in?

Answer (score 0):

This error is sometimes encountered when there is a problem with the RSA private key that you are using in your JWT request.  Start by verifying how you are passing your key's private data into the request, if you are reading from a environment variable for example make sure the key's value is contained on a single line, otherwise it might be getting truncated.

If your key spans multiple lines as an environment variable try doing a regular expression find/replace where you replace all newline `\n` characters with the string literal `"\n"` and then pass that through to see if it resolves your issue.